# Incorrect clipping in ggraph

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggraph

I'm using ggplot2 and ggraph to visualise graphs, but I have a problem with labels at the extremes of the x-axis. Here, labels stick out to the left and right and get clipped (see the left and right margins of the attached figure).

[image: Graph with labels incorrectly clipped]

Is there any way to disable clipping? Alternatively, is there any way to extend the x-range based on label sizes?

Comment: When using the dev version of `ggplot2`, one can use `coord_cartesian(clip = "off")` (as of two days ago). Alternatively, increase the `expand` parameter in `scale_x_continuous`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.